# How do I programmatically get an item on which I am performing a publish?

Tags: publishing, pipelines

How do I programmatically get an item on which I am performing publishing, irrespective of checkbox being checked (smart publish/ republish or publish related items or publish subitems)?

I don't want the whole publishing list just that item (the main item on which I clicked Publish->publish item). I have to make some code changes by modifying the publishing pipeline and not by event handler.

Comment: You find it.... in the publishing pipeline

Comment: You can easily find this in Publishing Handler ...var rootItem = publisher.Options.RootItem;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a publish pipeline processor, in order to get an item on which publishing is performed (the root item), you can use `PublishContext` and it's `PublishOptions.RootItem` property.
The class should be inherited from `Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishProcessor`.

***Note:*** You can get `RootItem` when `"Publish Item"` operation is used, but the property will be `null` when `"Publish Site"` is triggered.

The following example shows how to get publishing `RootItem` in a publishing pipeline processor:

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish;

namespace CustomProcessors
{
    public class YourPublishProcessor : PublishProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(PublishContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");

            //this is the item on which "Publish item" operation was triggered
            Item rootItem = context.PublishOptions.RootItem;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also find a bit more information [in this blog post](https://www.velir.com/blog/2013/11/22/how-create-custom-publish-queue-sitecore).
The `RootItem` will be available regardless of what publishing options are selected (smart publish/ republish or publish related items or publish subitems), but only available when `"Publish Item"` is triggered.

Comment: It worked . Thanks Sergey :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked, please click accept, if the answer was helpful.Thanks